# Next.js 13, "realtime" serverside data fetching

Tags: fetch, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Im trying to fetch data in realtime with next.js 13.

Unfortunately when i add new data my component does not update (I always need to do a browser refresh to see a new post).

Does "next: { revalidate: 0 }" not help for that? Do i really need to do a client component?

Thx for your advice in advance. I think this should be easy to solve :)

```
const getTopics = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/topics", {
      next: { revalidate: 0 } 
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch topics");
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error loading topics: ", error);
  }
};

export default async function TopicsList() {
  try {
    const response = await getTopics();

    if (!response || !response.topics) {
      throw new Error("Topics not found");
    }

    const { topics } = response;

    return (
      <>
        {topics.map((t) => (
          <div key={t._id} className="p-4 border border-slate-300 my-3 flex justify-between gap-5 items-start">
            <div>
              <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl">{t.title}</h2>
              <div>{t.description}</div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex gap-2">
              <RemoveBtn id={t._id} />
              <Link href={`/editTopic/${t._id}`}>
                <HiPencilAlt size={24} />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error loading topics: ", error);
    return <div>Error loading topics</div>;
  }
}
```